# ffmpeg reconnect to HLS stream

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

is it possible for ffmpeg to automatically respawn if a hls stream is disconnected and try to pick up from where it was dropped?

I have not tried to do it and i can't get my head around it. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you use the `-re` input option it waits instead of exiting

Comment: if i use -re and it waits... but what should it wait for? the thing is that the connection from the server is dropped and a new connection have to be re established. how will -re work? will it try to re establish the connection?

Comment: It will wait for new media segments to appear in the playlist for as long as the playlist is still reachable. Depending on what happens when your HLS stream goes away it *might* exit (404 or HTTP server not responding or got an EXT-X-ENDLIST when the stream stopped etc.). It can also get stuck if the input timestamps are not monotonically increasing.

Comment: how can i make it try to connect again if it gets EXT-X-ENDLIST?

Comment: Make a shell script which checks if it's down and tries to restart it.

Comment: maybe ask on the ffmpeg-user mailing list

Comment: the point is not making a script to connect when connection is lost. the point is instant connection and resume from the segment it was disconnected from.